# 2nd conditional and 3rd conditional flexibilty usage

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

Let's say your friend got into trouble **yesterday** because one of his co-workers was bullying him for no good reason, so your friend punched his co-worker on the face. *A day has passed*, then you just **told** to your friend this:

> If that happened to me, I would do it too (choice#1)
>
> If that had happened to me, I would have done it too (choice#2)

Are they **both valid to use** in this situation OR I should use **only one** of the these two?

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid and appropriate in terms of time reference, and both are grammatically correct. The second is far too florid for everyday discourse, though; in normal speech, the perfect is seldom used unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Are you an aussie? Your word usage is like that...

Comment: @JohnArvin Nothing antipodean about me, nope.